# et al. in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using bibtex for my bibliography.

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybibliography.bib}
```

I want my references to appear first author name, et al.
I tried to do that put it appears Random Name, and et al. How can I removed the word and?

Here is an example of my references:

```
@ARTICLE{Notohamiprodjo2015,
  author = {Notohamiprodjo, Mike and Chandarana, Hersh and Mikheev, Artem and
    Rusinek, Henry and Grinstead, John and Feiweier, Thorsten and Raya,
    Jose G. and Lee, Vivian S. and Sigmund, Eric E.},
  title = {Combined intravoxel incoherent motion and diffusion tensor imaging
    of renal diffusion and flow anisotropy.},
  journal = {Magn Reson Med},
  year = {2015},
  volume = {73},
  pages = {1526-1532},
  number = {4},
  month = {Apr},
  doi = {10.1002/mrm.25245},
  institution = {Center for Biomedical Imaging, Department of Radiology, NYU Langone
    Medical Center, New York, New York, USA; Department of Clinical Radiology,
    University Hospitals Munich, Munich, Germany; Department of Radiology,
    University Hospital Tuebingen, Tuebingen, Germany.},
  keywords = {Adult; Algorithms; Anisotropy; Blood Flow Velocity, physiology; Blood
    Volume, physiology; Diffusion Tensor Imaging, methods; Humans; Image
    Interpretation, Computer-Assisted, methods; Kidney, anatomy /&/ histology/physiology;
    Male; Reference Values; Renal Circulation, physiology; Reproducibility
    of Results; Sensitivity and Specificity; Young Adult},
  language = {eng},
  medline-pst = {ppublish},
  owner = {andrew},
  pmid = {24752998},
  timestamp = {2016.01.20},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/mrm.25245}
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid your write-up isn't very clear. First: the `plain` bibliography style can only create numeric-style citation call-outs. I would therefore assume that your objective pertains to the formatted bibliographic entries, not the citation call-outs. Is this assumption correct? Second, please clarify what you mean by "I tried to do that put it appears `Random Name, and et al.`". E.g., are you looking for code that picks a surname at random whenever an entry has two or more authors and displays the author list of that entry as `RandomName et al`?

Comment: Write `author = {Notohamiprodjo, Mike and others}`

Answer (score 1):

How about using another bib style instead?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{Notohamiprodjo2015}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{mybibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]